# Unable to get database items using Firebase observe listener for the first time

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have imported a simple json file and published on the realtime database called ("Quiz1"). I have then tried accessing it using the following code

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

print(ref.child("Quiz1").description())
ref.childByAutoId().observeSingleEvent(of:.value,  with: {snapshot in

    for child in snapshot.children  {

        print(child)
    }
}, withCancel: {error in print("WHAT")})
```

From what I can see in the documentation, this should trigger the first time the app is launched. But the code just skips over this part, I don't get any error. I have also changed the read/write permissions to make sure there are no authentication steps required at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the reference to a table in your `Firebase database` you need to call:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("your table name")
```

Then from here you can make a `listener` and get the values from the table

```
ref(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
```

Answer (score 0):

childByAutoId() creates new child under the ref and newly created node don't have any child nodes.
There's no child nodes to observe on your code.

If you are going to get nodes under "Quiz" please try below:

```
refHandle = ref.child("Quiz").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let quizDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
    // process quizDict
})
```

Comment: Well spotted on the `childByAutoId`. But that means the code attaches a value listener to a non-existing location, which should immediately trigger with `nil`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We can expect child values observing on existing node. Karthik sarpatwari imported json file and I suggest to confirm the child nodes from firebase console and try above code. In any case when observing child nodes don't need to use childByAutoId.

Comment: Thanks for all the edits and comments! I did try to listen on ref.child("Quiz1") and it still just goes past it. The childbyAutoId() was just one of the several random attempts to see if i could get it to work.

Comment: @karthiksarpatwari I edited, please try above code. Also please confirm Quiz child exist under the root and Quiz child node has child value.

Comment: @PaulStein - thanks. I think all the nodes are present - i have placed them here: https://tollyquiz-7733a.firebaseio.com/MyQuiz  I have changed the child node name now while i was trying to play with the json file to see if there was something wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to reference to the node "Quiz1", you need to access it using the `child` method something like this:
`ref.child("Quiz1")` and saving that reference in a variable (`refQuiz`), for then you can make queries (`observeSingleEvent`) with that reference (`refQuiz`).

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()    
let refQuiz = ref.child("Quiz1")

refQuiz.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

  for child in snapshot.children {
    print(child)
  }

}
```